# Copying data from different Excel worksheets in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop

I am using a Windows Desktop App and I wish to open a new Excel workbook and worksheet and then have the user select an existing Excel file so that the program can copy data onto the new sheet. The user should do this twice, since two Excel files are used for reference.

I know that to get the new Excel workbook and worksheet, you'd do the following:

```
Excel.Application oXL;
Excel._Workbook oWB;
Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
Excel.Range oRng;

oXL = new Excel.Application();
oXL.Visible = true;

//Get a new workbook.
oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
string sheetName = comboBox1.Text;
oSheet.Name = sheetName;
```

But where I get lost is how to reference the file that the user selects...
Would you do...

```
string excelPath = string.Empty;
using (OpenFileDialog excelFile = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    excelFile.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
    if(excelFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {

    }
}
```

After that how do I reference the data in the selected Excel file to, for example, extract everything from Column A and copy it into the new Excel file?

Comment: Is this the same as [your question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60922140/selecting-an-excel-file-for-reference-in-c-sharp), or an incremental step upon it?  As for "how to reference the file that the user selects", is [`excelFile.FileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename) what you're looking for?  You'd then need to read and present a list of sheets in that file for the user to select.

Comment: Pretty much. This question is more specific, but I'm unfamiliar with referencing. I did do .FileName but I dont think it did anything.

Comment: I've seen paths where the path is in the code already, but I want the user to determine the path, if that makes sense

Comment: Yes.  Inside of `if(excelFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)` you need to access `excelFile.FileName` because that contains the path of the file the user selected.

Comment: In the question the `OpenFileDialog` is named `excelFile`.  You need to take `excelFile.FileName` and do something with it, of course.  I'm not terribly familiar with the Excel automation API, but you'd load that path into a worksheet object to get the names of the sheets it contains, and then present another dialog to the user for them to select the sheet they want.

Comment: So would I equate the path with 'Excel._Workbook "excelFile"'?

Comment: Can't do that becuase it doesn't convert to string

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here.  I have added some tags to the question so perhaps someone more knowledgeable on the subject than myself will find it and assist.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little function I used in the past to do this through the interop's clipboard functionality:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public bool XlsCopyPaste(ref Workbook srcWb,
                         string srcSheetName, string srcRange,
                         ref Workbook tgtWb,
                         string tgtSheetName, string tgtRange,
                         XlPasteType pasteType)
{
    try
    {   
        var srcWs = srcWb.Sheets.Cast<Worksheet>().ToList();
        var tgtWs = tgtWb.Sheets.Cast<Worksheet>().ToList();

        var srcSheet = srcWs.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == srcSheetName);
        if (srcSheet != null)
        {
            var tgtSheet = tgtWs.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == tgtSheetName);
            if (tgtSheet == null)
            {
                tgtSheet = tgtWb.Sheets.Add();
                tgtSheet.Name = tgtSheetName;
            }

            var source = srcSheet.Range(srcRange);
            var target = tgtSheet.Range(tgtRange);

            source.Copy();
            target.PasteSpecial(pasteType, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);
        }
    }
    catch (Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
var xl = new Application();
var srcWb = (Workbook)xl.Workbooks.Open(xl.GetOpenFilename("Excel Workbooks (*.xls; *.xlsx),*.xls;*.xlsx").ToString());
var tgtWb = (Workbook)xl.Workbooks.Open(xl.GetOpenFilename("Excel Workbooks (*.xls; *.xlsx),*.xls;*.xlsx").ToString());

if (XlsCopyPaste(srcWb, "Sheet1", "B:C", tgtWb, "Sheet2", "A1", XlPasteType.xlPasteAll))
{
    tgtWb.Save();
}

srcWb.Close();
tgtWb.Close();

xl.Quit();
```

Comment: I think I'll just need the files, not the function. How would I reference a range or whatever if the file that the user opens is named MyExcel?

Comment: I don't understand your comment... I show an example on how you open two different files, providing a source and target sheet name and range. If you already know the file name, just pass it to the Open() call instead of GetOpenFilename.

Comment: User selects a file "MyExcel" . "NewExcel" opens. I want to copy whatever range I want from "MyExcel" into "NewExcel" programmatically

Comment: Look at the second part of the code in my answer. It does exactly that. Give it two workbook references, a source sheet name and range, a target sheet name and range, decide what you want to copy (everything, just data, just formulas, etc).

Comment: I see, but I want to do it without your function if I can. I was thinking something MyExcel.get_Range(Column A) then add that into NewExcel

Comment: Something like this? =[SourceWorkbook.xlsx]Sheet1!A1

Comment: You tagged your question with C#. I can't really help you with VBA macros or excel formulas...